# R Shinyapps io: Adjust package settings / increase cache

Tags: r, shiny, imagemagick, shinyapps

I'm running an R app on `shinyapps.io` and since my latest version I'm getting the error message that the cache is not enough for my operations. Specifically, the package in question is the `Magick` package.

But how can I increase the cache or change the settings of a package in `shinyapps.io`?

I am very grateful for any hint!

Comment: Assuming you're using images or clips, you can reduce the file size. Another option may be to optimize your code. The error is a limitation to whatever or whoever hosts your application.  [You could see if this resource helps.](https://engineering-shiny.org/optimizing-shiny-code.html) If you're getting this error on your PC, you shouldn't need to, but you could try garbage collection; enter `gc()` into the console.